# Thunderbolt 1.0 with New Monitors

Tags: macbook-pro, display, usb, thunderbolt, hdmi

I have never connected my MacBook to external monitors. I know I can use the HDMI port, but I was wondering about the Thunderbolt 1.0 port (I have 2 ports).

I am using a Mid 2012 15" retina MacBook Pro. Here are the monitors I am considering buying (2 units):

- [https://www.amazon.com/LG-Electronics-27MU88-W-27-Inch-LED-lit/dp/B01LG5RY74/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01LG5RY74)

I know I can't run these at full 4k with my laptop.

What do I need to use these monitors until I am able to upgrade the MacBook? These monitors don't have Thunderbolt 1.0 ports.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I probably wasn't specific enough. What adapter do I need as the monitors I am buying don't have Thunderbolt 1.0 ports.

Comment: The answer in the other question includes links to sites that can provide you the info for various types of connections.  Did you look at any of those?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see anything like that through all the massive amounts of information. Would you be so kind to provide a direct link?

Comment: @user145133 The important thing to know is that you wouldn't be connecting those monitors to a "Thunderbolt 1.0 port". The port on the computer doubles as a standard mini-DisplayPort. So you would just need a mini-DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable to connect a monitor with a DisplayPort input.

Comment: @jksoegaard thanks for the info. I think I got what I need. https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07NW9XKGL/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=ATXJQVAHAUH7D&psc=1